# Changing checkbox color prorammatically

Tags: java, android, checkbox, colors

I use this code:

```
tytMaths = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tytMaths);        
CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(tytMaths, ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.blue));
```

and it goes gray.
My `colors.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

    <color name="blue">#0DFFDC</color>
    <color name="green">#B8FF0D</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FFF90D</color>
    <color name="orange">#FFA00D</color>
    <color name="red">#FF3A0D</color>

</resources>
```

What should I do? It seems that my colors are correct. The problem is about the Java code, I think.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I edited. Actually my problem is this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ColorStateList.valueOf()` takes a color int, not a color resource int.

Use this instead:

```
ColorStateList.valueOf(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue))
```

Where `context` is whatever Context object you have access to. If this is inside an Activity, remove the `context.`. If it's inside a view, use `getContext().`.

Comment: Thank you mate <3 And there is parantheses after getResources that you'll want to edit :D

Comment: Whoops, yeah, it's a function call. I'm used to Kotlin, where you just need to use `context.resources`.